# Keep table line content in sight in table with very long cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table of the following format:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Single line | Single line | Very,    |
|             |             | very     |
|             |             | long     |
|             |             | text,    |
|             |             | going    |
|             |             | over     |
|             |             | multiple |
|             |             | screen   |
|             |             | pages    |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Next line   | ...         | ...      |
```

When scrolling the table, I have the problem that the "single line" entries get out of sight, which makes that table (even more) difficult to handle.

Is there a way to keep the single line entries in sight (inside their cell, of course), possibly with CSS or simple JavaScript/jQuery?

As for code, it is really just a HTML table on a page that has jQuery included:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head</th><th>Head</th><th>Head</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Short</td>
            <td>Short</td>
            <td>Long, long, long</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Short</td>
            <td>Short</td>
            <td>Long, long, long</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am not looking for a concrete solution but for a nudge into the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put the content in another element in `td`, such as `span`, then make it `position: sticky` and `top: 0`;

```css
table {
  max-width: 240px;
}

table tr td{
  vertical-align: top;
}

table tr td > *{
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Single Line</span></td>
    <td><span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut!</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Another Single Line</span></td>
    <td><span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum optio corporis alias esse. Veniam facilis odio doloribus nostrum molestias architecto! Doloremque cum exercitationem aspernatur corrupti, ullam blanditiis modi. Et, ut!</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! I have never heard of that `sticky` value before. Must be younger than 15 years. :-D

Comment: It is a rather new feature in css ;) so may not well supported by some old browsers, you might need to check the coverage via https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky